# ERROR:flask_oidc: ERROR: Unable to get token info - ERROR:flask_oidc:'token_introspection_uri'

Tags: python, flask, keycloak, openid-connect, flask-oauthlib

I have a Flask rest api that I'm calling from a Javascript client.
Trying to integrate Keycloak as an authentication server I had no success with flask (using flask_oidc) so I went for authenticating first from the javascript client (which works), and then usen the token to talk to the flask rest api.

However whenever I try to call a rest service with the token I get this error:

```
ERROR:flask_oidc:ERROR: Unable to get token info
  ERROR:flask_oidc:'token_introspection_uri'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
      response = self.handle_exception(e)
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
      return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
      reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
      raise value
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
      return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
      reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
      raise value
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
      rv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
      return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", line 860, in decorated
      return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/app/controller/engine.py", line 111, in welcome
      return json.dumps('Welcome %s' % g.oidc_token_info['sub'])
    File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
      return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'oidc_token_info'
```

This is my code, settings and keycloak.json in flask:

```
OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS='/app/keycloak.json',
OIDC_RESOURCE_SERVER_ONLY='true',
OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD='bearer'
```

...

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "MyClient",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "token_introspection_uri": "http://myservice_auth/auth/realms/myservice/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
    "token_uri": "http://myservice_auth/auth/realms/myservice/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "auth_uri": "http://myservice_auth/auth",
    "realm": "myservice",
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "resource": "MyClient",
    "public-client": true,
    "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
    "confidential-port": 0
  }
}
```

...

```
oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)

@app.route('/welcome', methods=['GET'])
@oidc.accept_token()
def welcome():
    return json.dumps('Welcome %s' % g.oidc_token_info['sub'])
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I downgraded httplib2 to 0.11.3 and now the error is:

```
ERROR:flask_oidc:ERROR: Unable to get token info
ERROR:flask_oidc:[Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
```

Also added `(require_token=True)` to the `@oidc.accept_token` decorator when defining the rest entrypoint, then in postman when I try to perform a get request to the service with the same token I got in the javascript client (successfully authenticated), I get this error:

`{"error": "invalid_token", "error_description": "Token required but invalid"}`

Comment: Where and how are you loading the keycloak json file?

Comment: Specifying it in the OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS option, just added it to the original post.

Comment: any updates on the answer? @magnoz I'm also using the same way and I too getting the same error.

Comment: Yes, mainly using the auth_uri that you get from the keycloak admin, adding this two other vars:     
    ```OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD='client_secret_post',```
```OIDC_TOKEN_TYPE_HINT='access_token'```   It worked for me in a "hello world" kind of a simple flask app. But I couldn't integrate it with my project yet, there it throws the same error. There might be another library interfering.